# Android Information Over USB

Tags: android, usb

I am going to be creating an application that requires me to take data via usb.  This data is going to basically be a simple string.  The interface I am plugging into is going to be a digital micrometer with a micro usb interface.  I was wondering if this is possible in any way.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. I hadn't done it before, but here is some guide:

[`USB Host and Accessory`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html)